# django rest framework : Is possible to create a put/patch request without using primary key?

Tags: python, django, http, django-rest-framework, rest

I want to update 2 fields is_exempted and comments from the data I get using put http method. And I can get multiple recommendation data from http method. And model doesn't have a field which I can consider pk for each account_id there can be multiple entries.

models.py

```
class Recommendation(models.Model):
    account             = models.ForeignKey(Accounts, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    account_name        = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    instance_id         = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    month_year          = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)    
    instance_type       = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    is_exempted         = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='no', null=False)
    comments            = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class RecommendationSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Recommendation
        fields = ( 'account_id', 'account_name', 'instance_id', 'instance_type', 'is_exempted', 'comments', 'month_year')
```

views.py

```
@api_view(['PUT'])
def update_recommendation_data(request):
    output = []
    if request.method == 'PUT':
        if request.data:
            for d in request.data:
                print(d)
                serializer = RecommendationSerializers(data=d, partial=False)
                if serializer.is_valid():
                    serializer.save()
                output.append(serializer.data)
        return Response(data=output, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    return Response(data="BAD REQUEST", status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
urlpatterns = [url("^", include(router.urls)),
url(r'^updaterecommendation$', views.update_recommendation_data)]
```

Comment: What is your url path for this view?

Comment: updated urls.py

Comment: I've posted an answer, did it helped? Did I miss something? Please let me know ;D

Comment: With Primary Key it's possible I know.. But I wanted to know without primary key if it is possible to perform patch or put. Because I will be getting account_id which not primary key, I can get all the records for that account_id ...and I've to update is_exempted and comments for all the data which I will get from request.data. Note - account_id, instance_id and month_year can uniquely identify one row.

Comment: So, your idea is to send multiple Recommendation objects within one request?

Comment: yes, I was thinking if that's possible. Otherwise I'll have to make multiple backend calls.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at what you've said:

> And model doesn't have a field which I can consider pk for each account_id there can be multiple entries.

As I understood you are facing a problem to determine a key to use to identify each recommendation individually. But you already have such a key, follow along.

Your model already have a primary key as per [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields):

> An id field is added automatically, but this behavior can be overridden. See [Automatic primary key fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields).

So you can filter it by sending the `id` field auto generated by Django.